# how to get information for specific user in Django ( i wanted to get Appointment history for specific user who is now logged in )

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

#for for adding appointment

```
def book_appointment(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        specialization=request.POST['specialization']
        doctor_name=request.POST['doctor']
        time=request.POST['time']
        app=Appointment(specialization=specialization, doctor_name=doctor_name, time=time)
        app.save()  
    messages.success(request, "Successfully Appointment booked tap on view appointment for status")
    return redirect('home')
```

#view appointment history

```
  def appointmentInfo(request):
    appts= Appointment.objects.all() 
    return render(request,'home/view_appointment.html',{'appoints':appts})
```

#login

```
def handeLogin(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        # Get the post parameters
        loginusername=request.POST['loginusername']
        loginpassword=request.POST['loginpassword']
        user=authenticate(username= loginusername, password= loginpassword)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Successfully Logged In")
            return redirect("home")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid credentials! Please try again")
            return redirect("home")  
    return HttpResponse("404- Not found") 
    return HttpResponse("login")
```

Comment: include the details of the `Appointment` model in your post.

Comment: class Appointment(models.Model):
     sno= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     doctor_name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
     specialization= models.CharField(max_length=23)
     fee=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #  email= models.CharField(max_length=100)
     time= models.TextField()
     timeStamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

Comment: there is no relation between the `Appointment` Model and logged-in user i.e `request.user`. You need to extract the appointments using the `email` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the records of the current User,

add a relationship attribute pointing the appointments model to the Users model so as to know who is the patient being treated... something like this ,

**Models.py:**

```
#import for User model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Appointment(models.Model):
    sno= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    doctor_name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    specialization= models.CharField(max_length=23)
    fee=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #email= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #time= models.TextField()
    #timeStamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def appointmentInfo(request):

    appts= Appointment.objects.get(user__id = request.user.id)

    return render(request,'home/view_appointment.html',{'appoints':appts})
```

Comment: `get` will raise an error if multiple objects are returned. you should use `filter`.

Comment: @VishalSingh that why I have mentioned to use the primary key.

Comment: request.user gives the current user. Appointments.objects.all() gives all the appointments in the db, so you need to filter the querry by setting the primary key

Comment: `request.user.id` will be different from `Appointment`  id so this approach will not work.

Comment: yes. he has no foreign key to users in his models. So he has to add another field in  htemodels to match with the users database

Comment: home.Appointment.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
home.Appointment.user: (fields.E307) The field home.Appointment.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'home.user', but app 'home' doesn't provide model 'user'.

Comment: you have to import Users in your model. i have edited in the model. check

Comment: i have changed the user reference as OnetoOnefield in models,.. try with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229804/discussion-between-tushar-patil-and-sangeeth-subramoniam).